# Real time transfer the Couchbase data to Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, couchbase

I am trying to transfer (the incremental data added to) the CouchBase data to Kafka topic.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout "Quickstart" section of the documentation. Sidebar there also includes more details about Couchbase Kafka connector.

https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/connectors/kafka-3.1/quickstart.html